# Core Data prevent saving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is there a way to prevent specific `NSManagedObjectModel` from being saved based on a specific condition?

I know we can use `willSave` to modify the object before saving, but is there a way to prevent an object from being saved?

```swift
override public func willSave() {

    if self.name != nil {

       // Save the object into context
    }
    else {
       // Don't save the object into context
    }
}
```

The reason for this request is that the user should be able to start a form and insert some of the values, then he can also go to other screens and do something else that can trigger `context.save()` and I don't want the form to be saved if it is not completed.

I need to create this object in context since the object has a relationship to another object in context and if I create the object outside the context, I will need to change the context for all relationships.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would typically use a child context for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you mention you'd rather not use different conext, but using a different context is the best way really.

If you create on your main context, even without saving, the data is still 'in context'. Separating out is safest. 
Creating a child context from your main context...

```
let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

childContext.parent = YOUR_MAIN_THREAD_CONTEXT
```

you now create your `NSManagedObject` using this child context and if the user leaves without completing then simply set this context to nil and it's away.

If you want to commit it, then save the child context, which *pushes it to **main***, then save the main context to push to persistent store

```
func commitContext(childContext: NSManagedObjectContext?) {

    do {
        try childContext?.save()
        do {
            try MainThreadMoc.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving parent context")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving childContext")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you for the comment. This looks like a great solution, however, the form has a relationship to another object which is in the main context. If I change the context for the form, I will have to change the context for the related object and to its related objects and so on...

Comment: Hi @Sam, np. I see, In understand there's always more to it from the initial description. Good luck with the final solution though.

Comment: In order to use another object that has a relationship to my object which is on the child context, I found this solution: `childContext.object(with: RelatedObj.objectID) as! RelatedObj`. So I was able to get the other object on the child context and then link both objects together. Thank you for your help. It really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

If the context doesn't have uncommitted changes when the form is presented you could use the [rollback()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506942-rollback) API. It

> removes everything from the undo stack, discards all insertions and deletions, and restores updated objects to their last committed values.

```
override public func willSave() {

    if self.name != nil {
       try? context.save()
    }
    else {
       context.rollback()
    }
}
```